# PHP 5.3 on CentOS does not work.

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, lamp

On a CentOS, PHP 5.3 is installed, but does not work, do you have to somehow *start* something?

Apache is started and `Apache 2 Test Page` is displayed alright. I added a testphp.php file with the following and browsing to the file just shows the source:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarted apache and now it works.